# @RequestMapping for @Component Bean

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Just a simple question. Does `@RequestMapping` only works with `@Controller` classes. I am trying to map a `@Component` bean in my application using `@RequestMapping` and its always throwing **noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite right, you can only use `@RequestMapping` on `@Controller` annotated classes. From the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) of the `@Controller` class:

> Base Controller interface, representing a component that receives HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse instances just like a HttpServlet [...]

In addition, the `@Controller` *extends* the `@Component` bean, [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html):

> [@Component] Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

In other words, a `@Component` (and its sub-annotation `@Controller`) is what makes a class a Spring bean, but only the `@Controller` annotation deals with `@RequestMapping` and other HTTP related operations.

There is more information about *stereotype annotations* in the Spring [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations).